# Script doesn't execute, rather it hangs

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that I want to run every minute on my web server to check the last 3 lines of log file to see what the memory usage is for the program.  The script works as in gets the correct result for the memory but I can't get it to email or exit - it just hangs?

Any ideas on why this doesn't exit? And is this the best approach to run as a cron on the server to tail the last 3 lines of the log?

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/home/user/Scripts/test.txt
SERVER=/home/user/Scripts/local/case.txt
CASE=$(head -n 1 $SERVER)

grep INFO: | grep Memory $LOG | awk '{print $9}' | tail -n 3 | while read output;
do
  #echo $output
  new=$(echo $output)
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  mag=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  if [ $new -lt 10 ]; then
  echo $new
  mail -s "TEST" - Alert: Memory usage is at $usep%" "user@examplecom" <<< \
  " \"$CASE \" - Memory usage is currently peaked to \"$mag ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as   on $(date)"
  echo "email"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Can you run the mail line in the shell? What does `<<<` do there?

Comment: add `set -x` just below `#!/bin/bash` line and run the script from command line to see what's happening. And pls pls give a better title to your question.

Comment: Sorry about the question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `grep` is reading standard input. Unless you invoke this with a redirection (please show us!) that's why it appears to hang -- it's waiting for you to type in some input.

As a quick fix, change

```
grep INFO: | grep Memory $LOG | awk ...
```

to read

```
grep INFO: "$LOG" | grep Memory | awk ...
```

(The double quotes are not strictly necessary here, but a good idea to learn for the future.)

Much better, refactor the multiple `grep`s and the `tail` into the `awk` script:

```
awk '/INFO:/ && /Memory/ { g[NR%3+1] = $0 }
    END { for (j=1; j<=3; ++j) print g[j] }' "$LOG"
```

If the order of the output is significant, you have to fiddle it a bit more.

Also, `new=$output` is vastly preferable over `new=$(echo $output)` unless you specifically require word splitting, in which case `set -- $output` is both safer and more idiomatic. See also http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo

Comment: Yes, you should move $LOG to the first grep.

Comment: Ahh thank you - yes it was the grep waiting for input - thanks